# The difference between two mean differences

Tags: t-test

I'm an English teacher who is writing his MA thesis and I don't have much knowledge in statistics required for my research and I would like to ask you for a solution to my problem (if there is one).

I will give you a much simplified example of what my study is about. I have a Polish student who is learning English. I wanted to test the effectiveness of a pronunciation teaching technique and to see if he can produce English vowels better. I did a test before the treatment and another one after it with the hope of verifying potential progress.

In short, I wanted to see, for example, if in the English word "beach" he uses the proper long English /i:/ or his Polish native vowel (Polish /i/ is similar in quality but much shorter). I recorded his three productions of "beach" (the words were embedded in English sentences and he was told to try to say them in English) and then three productions of the Polish word "bicz" (this word sounds very similar to "beach" but has shorter /i/).

In a speech visualisation software I measured the durations of the English /i:/ in the three "beach"es and calculated the average duration (in milliseconds) based on those three samples. I did the same thing with three Polish /i/s in the "bicz" words. I made this measurement in both languages in the pre-test and in the post-test. Here are the results:

Pre-test:
Average English /i:/ duration: 161 ms (std. dev. = 19)

Average Polish /i/ duration: 98 ms (std. dev. = 5)

Average difference: 63 ms

Post-test:
Average English /i:/ duration: 243 ms (std. dev. = 43)

Average Polish /i/ duration: 86 ms (std. dev. = 10)

Average difference: 157 ms

My question is: how can I compare those two average differences (63 and 157)? My (probably oversimplified idea) was to just subtract one from the other and say that, since the average difference was bigger in the post-test than in the pre-test, the treatment worked because the English-Polish difference in the duration of /i/ was greater in the post-test, but it all doesn't seem very statistically sound. Should I perhaps calculate the p-values for the pre-test difference and the post-test difference and compare those p-values?

Note: I presented a much simplified example of what I'm really doing. The majority of my samples include so called formant values (not durations) of different vowels in different words and they must each time be compared across the two languages because they are not very stable (in either of the languages). Therefore, I could not just record and measure only their English words in the tests (which obviously would be much easier). Also, I actually have three tests because I expose my subjects to two kinds of treatments, but I first wish to find a solution to the simplified problem I presented.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your description as follows:

For the pre-training measurements you have three sessions.
In each session you measured English minus Polish duration.
Call the three differences $X_1, X_2, X_3.$ Their mean is 63ms.
From what you say, I'm not sure of about the standard deviation
of these three differences. Maybe as large as 20, likely smaller.

Similarly, for the post-training measurement you also have
three sessions. In each session you again measured English minus
Polish duration. Call the three differences $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3.$
Their mean is 157. Maybe their standard deviation is as large as 44.

Assuming differences to be roughly normally distributed, you might
do a Welch 2-sample t test to compare the sample mean of the
X's with the sample mean of the Y's.

You don't have much data with only three differences before
and three differences after pronunciation training. I can't
do the computation without knowing the six differences (or
without being sure about the two standard deviations). It is possible
that you may find a significant difference.

If you provide the data, I can do the test. Otherwise, I hope
you can figure out how to do it from a formula in a statistics
text or using software.

Comment: "In each session you measured English minus Polish duration"
It was little different than that, I think. In the pre-test (and the post test) the subject read the English word "beach" three times and I calculated the average duration value for English /i:/ in that word (161 ms in pre-test). Then, he read three instances of the Polish word "bicz" three times, which gave the average of 98 ms (in pre-test) for Polish short /i/. And then I simply did 161-98 = 63.
The same happened in the post-test, which gave the difference of 157.

Comment: I heard of the test to see if, for example, 161 ms and 98 ms (the averages in pre-test) are significantly different, but I can't imagine how to verify the significance between the average difference in pre-test  (63 ms) and the average difference in post test (157).